# what is correct maximum number of subnetworks?

Tags: computer-networks

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

ip: 10.5.2.1

subnetmask: 255.255.255.240

{10.5.2.1/28}

what is correct maximum subnetworks ????

what is different between classful subnet and CIDR subnet ???

Comment: This is not a CS question, consider asking it on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).